# Trouble closing a csv to delete it

Tags: python, operating-system, smtplib

I've got a daily task that is a perfect candidate for automation so I decided to use it as a project to learn Python. What I need to do is convert a few .xlsx files to .csv and then email each to a specific email address.

Below is what I've got and it works just fine up until near the end. I want it to delete the csv copies after they've been sent. File1.csv gets deleted but file2.csv does not because it is still open in another process.

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Drop\file2.csv'

So it's clear the csv needs to be closed but I just can't manage to figure out which process has it open and how to close it.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

files = []

drop_path = 'C:\\Data Drop\\'
path = os.chdir(drop_path)
datestamp =  datetime.now().strftime(' (%m-%d-%Y)')

#Make a CSV copy of each file
for c in os.listdir(path):
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(c)
    xlsx = pd.read_excel(file_name+file_ext)
    xlsx.to_csv(file_name+'.csv', encoding='utf-8')
    files.append(file_name+'.csv')

print('CSV copies created\n')

#Send to appropriate email addresses
recipient = ''
for s in files:

    print('Sending ',s)

    if s == 'file1.csv':
        recipient = '<email1@gmail.com>'
    elif s == 'file2.csv':
        recipient = '<email2@gmail.com>'

    email_user = 'sender@gmail.com'
    email_password = 'password'
    email_send = recipient

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = "Data transmittal"

    body = 'Data transmittal attached'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

    attached_file = s
    attachment  = open(attached_file,'rb')

    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+attached_file)

    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,email_password)


    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    print(s,'sent.\n')
    server.quit()

print('All data has been sent.\n')

#Remove CSV files once sent.
for files in os.listdir(drop_path):
    if files.endswith('.csv'):
        os.remove(drop_path + files)

print('CSV files cleared.\n')

#Add the date to the end of each xlsx file name
for f in os.listdir(path):
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if file_ext==".csv":
        continue
    else:
        new_name = file_name+datestamp+file_ext
        os.rename(f, new_name)

print('Dates added to file names.\n')

print('\nAll operations are complete.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is opening `attachment` and never closing it.

instead of : `attachment  = open(attached_file,'rb')`

use [`with open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) context manager:

```py
with open(attached_file,'rb') as attachment:
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
# here attachment is closed automatically
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+attached_file)
```